# Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with bipartition $X$ and $Y$ having a matching from $X$ into $Y$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Prove that there is a vertex $x\in X$ such that every edge incident with $x$ is contained in some matching from $X$ into $Y$.

Comment: Are you familiar with Hall's theorem? One way to do this is to carefully examine its proof.

Comment: I just learnt Hall's theorem. Can you give some hints on this?

Comment: I see. I need to show a subset on which Hall's condition critically holds. And use induction, like in the proof for Hall's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably:

- A *[matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29)* in this context means *perfect matching* (also known as a [1-factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-factor)), otherwise the claim is trivially true without the conditions placed on the graph (the individual edges themselves form a matching).
- A *[bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph)* should say a *[regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph) bipartite graph*, otherwise the claim is false.  Counterexample:

[image: The orange edge does not belong to any perfect matching]

The orange edge in the above bipartite graph does not belong to any perfect matching, despite the graph itself having a perfect matching.

---

If the above bullet points are correct, then [Hall's Marriage Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) can be used to prove the existence of a 1-factorisation (and thus every edge belongs to a perfect matching).

A sketch of the required steps:

- For vertices $v \in X$, defined $S_v$ to be the set of neighbours of $v$.  Hence we have a family of sets $\mathcal{S}=\{S_v\}_{v \in X}$.
- Show that, for any $W \subseteq \mathcal{S}$, the marriage condition is satisfied for $W$, that is, $$|W| \leq \left| \bigcup_{A \in W} A \right|.$$
- Conclude that the graph has a perfect matching, and thus, by induction, contains a 1-factorisation.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/266261/139), I explain how to use Hall's Marriage Theorem in the context of $(0,1)$-matrices (which are equivalent to bipartite graphs via their biadjacency matrix; see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)).